# Learn Azure practical skills without paying or providing my card info

Tags: azure, free

Is it possible to learn Azure practical skills without paying or providing my card info?

I found out about the https://portal.azure.com/. And about the modular tutorials https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/browse/?products=azure. But I am not sure whether or not it will be feasible for me to cover all important for the commercial development topics with just the free resources above.

Maybe there are other ways to learn Azure profoundly without paying or providing my card info? It is an important question for me, because I really want to learn Azure a lot, but if there is no free plan to learn it, then I will have to pick something else (e.g. AWS or Heroku).

Here learning Azure implies being able to access theoretical knowledge base and documentation (both of which I am sure are present) and also being able to use a fully free (and without any card info) sandbox environment. And the question is a doubt that such a free sandbox environment exists.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/?

Comment: @GauravMantri, the link you provided implies that I will have to provide the card info. Which I do not want to do.

Comment: I use some free or almost free (some dollars, or some cents) Azure services, like App Service, Azure Functions, they only charged $1 one time on my new Subscription and I think that the $1 charge was automatically reverted. I guess that the card info is for security reasons, and also when your app gets more users, you are already configured, only have to add funds to the card.

Comment: If you have an educational email (ends in .edu), you can use the [student offer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/students/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a while I was able to come over the Azure sandboxes. And that is what I was looking for in the question. E.g. [this](https://medium.com/@lukaszgasior/how-to-learn-azure-with-a-free-sandbox-subscription-8ad9f457ea88) article explains how to use them.

Comment: How is this answer better than my answer? The Azure sandboxes can only be used as part of Microsoft Learn. They are not a separate resource that you can access without a Microsoft Learn account.

Comment: @JohnHanley, in my question I was looking for the sandboxes and you mentioned nothing about them. Don`t take it personally, please.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Learn resource is very good and free. I use it all the time. However, not every learning module is free. Some require an account. This might be around 5% that require your own Azure account.

Can you learn Azure for free with Microsoft Learn? Absolutely YES. There are almost 1,000 modules on the site to choose from. I recommend this site even for very experienced Azure developers. For example, the VPN Gateway modules are free to practice with.

[Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/browse/)